# React Hook setValue() not working inside EventSource.onmessage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, server-sent-events

I'm using SSE to get a stream of strings, which I need to store in a useState to display it word by word. However, after I have changed the state and the component rerenders, the old state is retained OUTSIDE the `eventSource.onmessage` function. As soon as it comes inside it, the state gets the default value.

```
const [currentResp, setCurrentResp] = useState('');
  const [respHistory, setRespHistory] = useState({
    count: 0,
    queryName: null,
    queryData: [],
  });

  console.log('currentResp after it has been changed', currentResp);

  const toggleRequest = () => {
    if (query == respHistory.queryName) {
      console.log('asd');
    } else {
      setRespHistory({
        count: 1,
        queryName: query,
        ...respHistory,
      });
    }

    const url = 'https://somesseurl/sse';
    const sse = new EventSource(url);

    function getRealtimeData(data) {
      console.log('Inside Function currentResp - ', currentResp);
      const currentSSEText = data.choices[0].text;
      setCurrentResp(currentResp + currentSSEText);
    }

    sse.onmessage = (e) => getRealtimeData(JSON.parse(e.data));
    sse.onerror = (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      sse.close();
    };
    return () => {
      sse.close();
      console.log('Closed');
    };
  };
```

I want to retain the old state even inside the function, such that I keep concatinating the string stream that is coming from the SSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because you are using the current state reference to update the state.

```
setCurrentResp(currentResp + currentSSEText);
```

In react, the state updates are asynchronous, so when you update any state react puts that state update inside a queue, and then react will execute the state updates one by one from the queue and the state will be updated.

So when you're trying to update the state using the `currentResp` as the previous state value, it may not work because `currentResp` may not have the latest value.

So if you want to access the previous state value inside a state update, you can do it like below

```
setCurrentResp((prev) => {
  return prev + currentSSEText
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm not aware of this "queue" system that react follows. Do you have any articles or references that I can refer to so that I can learn about it?

Comment: This article might help you understand it better. 
https://the-guild.dev/blog/react-hooks-system